# Asp.net controls look different depending on browser

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Developing in Web Forms I noticed that controls have different sizes and styles deppending on which borwser I launch the application. For instance, In IE the buttons and textboxes are thicker than those in Chrome.

Is there a way to make all of them look the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, many things on the web look different across browsers.  If you are really committed to making them appear the same, use your own CSS rules to try and standardize the look, or implement 3rd party controls that attempt to account for this such as DevExpress or Telerik controls.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to make it all the same. You would confuse your users. chrome users do not expect to have thicker buttons. Most users have a favorite browser and they know its design. As long as you produce valid html and css, everything is fine.